# Camera not able to connect

Tags: rooting, rom-flashing

I rooted my Micromax canvas HD phone and flashed a ROM. After which if I click on the camera app it says that it cannot connect to camera. This is only for back camera, the front camera works fine. This is the second ROM I flashed and a friend of mine flashed the same ROM on the same model. So why isn't the camera working on mine?

Comment: Hard to help you here, Amit, if you not even mention *which* ROM you've flashed. I recommend asking where you've downloaded it. It might even be a known limitation (yes, this sometimes happens with custom ROMs – and usually these limitations are pointed out).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bug in the ROM, a lot of ROMs come with bugs which is why you should choose well built ones, like cyanogen mod, You could always try reverting to your previous ROM is you don't get this fixed.

Comment: Didn't you mean Cyanogenmod (Stable) since it also has Nightlies which are meant to have bugs?

Comment: yes thats what i meant,